# DatePlus changes in V10.2, can I return to previous behaviour?

Tags: date-and-time

Now in V10.2, `DatePlus` has changed it behaviour in a undocumented way.

Now, `DatePlus[n]` (with n as `Integer`) return current date in the format:

`{year, month, day, hour, minute, second}`

Instead of:

`{year, month, day}`.

There is some parameter that controls that? So I can return to old behaviour?

IMHO this is a very bad practice. Make version update much more hard, and can easy break old code.

Comment: The best practice is to always use DateValue when working with Dates. This decouples your code from the way that these date functions will choose to represent their output.

Comment: @Searke, this is a nice tip. I have never used `DateValue`.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
   With[{DatePlus = Function[Null, Take[DatePlus[##], 3]]},
           stuff;
           DatePlus[2]
   ]
```

Comment: Why not `With[{DatePlus = Take[DatePlus[##], 3] &}, (* stuff *) DatePlus[2]]` or even `With[{DatePlus = DatePlus[##][[;; 3]] &}, (* stuff *) DatePlus[2]]`?